# how to fix mongodb broken installation

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

> i install mongo db from a website guide then i folllowed the step until i got this error on installation

> I was try using install -f & apt update --fix-missing but still not working

```
root@danil-Lenovo-ideapad-120S-14IAP:/usr/bin# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/77,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 266 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 267730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.6.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.6.18) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_3.6.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.6.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.6.18) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_3.6.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.6.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.6.18) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_3.6.18_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_3.6.18_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you reinstall?

Comment: Try uninstalling version 3.6.3 and then reinstall 3.6.18

Comment: i was reinstall but mongodb cannot start service